# How to create nested PHP value object? (class)

Tags: php, arrays, class

I would like to create the following using class syntax:

```
$resp = new stdclass;

$resp->CategoryListResp->category[0]->categoryId = 1;
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[0]->categoryName = "Spel"; 
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[0]->iconUri = "PictoSpel.png";

$resp->CategoryListResp->category[1]->categoryId = 2;
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[1]->categoryName = "Transport";
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[1]->iconUri = "PictoTransport.png";
```

Should be easy but I cannot find the syntax for this.
I will later output $resp in json format. I am aware I can also use arrays for this...

The json output shall be:

```
{"CategoryListResp":{"category":[{"categoryId":1,"categoryName":"Spel","iconUri":"PictoSpel.png"},{"categoryId":2,"categoryName":"Transport","iconUri":"PictoTransport.png"}]}}
```

Comment: Yes, use arrays, it is **much** simpler... if you want to use objects, well, you first have to assign an empty object to `$resp->CategoryListResp`, like you did for `$resp`, and so on...

Comment: Are you running into problems? That code should work as is.

Comment: The code works fine but I would like to know how to make more explicit classes. The json above is output with a simple 
`print json_encode($resp);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also make your classes more explicit:

```
    class Category {
        public $categoryId = 0, $categoryName = '', $iconUri = '';
    }

    class Resp {
        public $categoryListResp = null;
        public function __construct() {
            $this->categoryListResp = new CategoryListResp();
        }
    }

    class CategoryListResp {
        public $category = array();
    }

    $resp = new Resp();
    $resp->categoryListResp->category[0]->categoryId = 1; 
    $resp->categoryListResp->category[0]->categoryName = "Spel";  
    $resp->categoryListResp->category[0]->iconUri = "PictoSpel.png"; 
    // etc.
```

ADDED (based on henq's comment). To fully utilize the class concept you would need to add some methods to the classes. Then you would not use `->` for arrays, but call the respective methods. E.g.

```
class Category {
    public $categoryId = 0, $categoryName = '', $iconUri = '';
    public function __construct($id, $name, $icon) {
        $this->categoryId = $id;
        $this->categoryName = $name;
        $this->iconUri = $icon;
    }
}

class Resp {
    public $categoryListResp = null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->categoryListResp = new CategoryListResp();
    }
    public function addCategory($index, $id, $name, $icon) {
        $this->categoryListResp->addCategory($index, $id, $name, $icon);
    }
}

class CategoryListResp {
    public $category = array();
    public function addCategory($index, $id, $name, $icon) {
        $this->category[$index] = new Category($id, $name, $icon);
    }
}

$resp = new Resp();        
$resp->addCategory(0, 1, "Spel", "PictoSpel.png");
$resp->addCategory(1, 2, "Transport", "PictoTransport.png");
// etc
```

You can modify this concept according to your needs.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was looking for. But I can see now that you do not gain much by explicitly define the classes. I ended up just using arrays which seems to be "the PHP way" :)

Comment: Indeed I did it only half way to show the concept and to keep your `->` notation for the construction. I extended my answer to show the full power of the class concept. But again, you likely need to adapt it to your needs

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there already:

```
$resp = new stdClass();
$resp->CategoryListResp = new stdClass();

$resp->CategoryListResp->category[0]->categoryId = 1;
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[0]->categoryName = "Spel"; 
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[0]->iconUri = "PictoSpel.png";

$resp->CategoryListResp->category[1]->categoryId = 2;
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[1]->categoryName = "Transport";
$resp->CategoryListResp->category[1]->iconUri = "PictoTransport.png";

print_r(json_encode($resp));

/* 
output:
{"CategoryListResp":{"category":[{"categoryId":1,"categoryName":"Spel","iconUri":"PictoSpel.png"},{"categoryId":2,"categoryName":"Transport","iconUri":"PictoTransport.png"}]}}
*/
```

Just send `$resp` to [json_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Your code should work as is, however. It's better design to create class definitions for `CategoryListResp` and `Category`, rather than just using `stdClass`.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are the simpler way to go (as suggested by @felix-kling)

This is how the code ended up:

```
$resp = array(
  'CategoryListResp' => array(
    'category' => array(
      array(
        'categoryId'   => 1,
        'categoryName' => 'Spel',
        'iconUri'      => 'PictoSpel.png'
      ),
      array(
        'categoryId'   => 2,
        'categoryName' => 'Transport',
        'iconUri'      => 'PictoTransport.png'
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

print json_encode($resp);
```

Clean and simple.