# how can i retrive customer name in stripe php slim

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments, slim

server side

```html
<?php
  $app->get('/order', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $id = $_GET['sessionId'];
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($id);
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($checkout_session->customer);

    echo json_encode($customer);
  });
$app->run();
```

client side codes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order Confirm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="checkout">
            <div id="payment-forum">
                <h1>Success</h1>
                <section class="order">
                    <li>name <span id="customer_name"></span></li>
                </section>
                 payment status: <span id="payment-status"></span>
                 <pre>
                    
                 </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var paymentStatus = document.getElementById('payment-status');
    var customer = document.getElementById('customer_name');
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var sessionId = urlParams.get("session_id")
    if (sessionId) {
    fetch("/order?sessionId=" + sessionId).then(function(result){
        return result.json()
    }).then(function(session){
        var sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session, null, 2);
        document.querySelector("pre").textContent = sessionJSON;
        paymentStatus.innerText = session.payment_status;
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('Error when fetching Checkout session', err);
    });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

hi

i was working on success page i do see whole payment intent on my screen but i want to pick name of customer and payment status only and why does it print whole payment intent.

thanks in advance for helping out

edited------------------------------

```html
paymentStatus.innerText = session.payment_status;
```

i manage to get payment status but if i change $customer to $checkout_session

but as one gentlemen said call for $checkout_session is risky and if i use $customer what javascript of payment status be

> paymentStatus.innerText = session.payment_status;

and how will i manage to take other things like metadata, price, email which are not part of customer

edited 2--------------------------------------------

like i did some changes for extra safety like if i send those values in backend so whole intent wont be exposed so i got another problem

```html
$app->get('/order', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
  $id = $_GET['sessionId'];
  $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve($id);
  $amount = $checkout_session->amount_total;
  $payment_status = $checkout_session->payment_status;
  

  echo json_encode([$payment_status,$amount]);
});
```

i do get only amount in front end to catch this in front end i did some changes like

```js
<script>
    var paymentStatus = document.getElementById('payment-status');
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount1');
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var sessionId = urlParams.get("session_id")
    if (sessionId) {
    fetch("/order?sessionId=" + sessionId).then(function(result){
        return result.json()
        
    }).then(function(session){
        var sessionJSON = JSON.stringify(session, null, 2);
        document.querySelector("pre").textContent = sessionJSON;
        amount.innerText = session;
        paymentStatus.innerText = session;
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log('Error when fetching Checkout session', err);
    });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

but now the problem is i can only have one value how will i add payment status also in it

> echo json_encode([$amount, $payment_status])

dosent works and if it work also how will iget both values for seperate id in client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so a couple things here.  I would start by logging the `$id` and `$checkout_session` to be 100% sure of the data you are retrieving server-side before you send it to the client. Your code should not be returning a [Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) at any point.  You may be returning the entire [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object), in which case logging all retrieved values on your server should help identify which variables are holding what values at runtime.

AFAIK The only PHP client maintained by Stripe is [this one](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php).  If this isn't the version you are using I would consider switching.

Another thing to consider is how you retrieve the Customer object.  You can expand the `Customer` property so the full object is returned instead of just the `id`.  You can read about expanding responses [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects).  In your case the request would look something like this (revised instantiation of Stripe library following current syntax):

```php
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient("sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXX");
$checkout = $stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve(
  'cs_test_XXXXXXXXXXX',
  ['expand' => ['customer']]
);
```

From here you could return the Customer object directly from `$checkout->customer`.

Comment: okey i got your point and on my screen it shows only customer property but now i got into situation where i can get customer name but cant fetch payment status, amount , email and meta data

Comment: The `metadata` and `customer_email` are separate properties of the Checkout object.  The amount and and status can be found on the `payment_intent` property _if you expand it_.  You can pass all of this to your front-end but that is insecure.  

Try building a custom JSON object with all the data you want to display and return that to the client.

Comment: can you provide example of custom JSon objects

Comment: did some changes see if you could help on it

Comment: best part of this website is when you ask question you start getting ideas way faster , 
server side 
echo json_encode([$payment_status,$amount]); i did this and i  can see those results on page but both of them are assign to single class id how do i sperate them

Comment: I'm not an expert in building nested objects in PHP but thankfully someone else on SO has already run into that issue.  Take a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321997/how-to-create-nested-php-value-object-class

Comment: got it its like return (['id' => $value, 'id' => $value2])

Comment: but thanks a lot you showed me way i appreciate your efforts.